# Eslint throwing "Parsing error: Unexpected token" while using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, gsap

I installed `@types/greensock` and started using `gsap` with `TypeScript`. Everything works fine, but the `ScrollTo` plugin is giving this `eslint` error (image attached). Does someone know something about it?

Here is the eslint error:

[image]

Here is my `.eslintrc`:

```js
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true
  }
}
```

Here is my code:

```js
import { ScrollToPlugin } from "gsap/ScrollToPlugin";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollToPlugin);

export const headerInteractionHandler = () => {
  document.querySelector("header .logo").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let element = <HTMLAnchorElement>e.currentTarget;

    gsap.to(window, {
      duration: 0.8,
      scrollTo: `${element.getAttribute("data-destination")}`,
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been told on the GreenSock forum that I shouldn't be using `@types/greensock` as `gsap` has built-in support for TypeScript. So I deleted it, and I updated my `.eslintrc` by replacing `babel-eslint` with `@typescript-eslint/parser` like below, and the problem is gone.

Needed installs:

```
npm i @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser --save-dev
```

.eslintrc:

```js
{
  
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ]
}
```